# How does Excel handle formulas with unavailable paid Office 365 features?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, fallback

I want to include the built-in data currency conversion grab in my spreadsheet, and this is a paid Office 365 feature. This is fine for me.

But if somebody opens my spreadsheet, and they don't have an Office 365 subscription, what happens? I presume many functions become unavailable, but in what way?

- Do such cells produce an error of sorts?
- Do the cells preserve their most recent value, but become static?

I haven't been able to find an explanation of "before vs after" for Excel spreadsheets regarding Office 365 subscribers vs Office 365 non-subscribers, and I'm not aware of how to simulate a non-subscriber.

Given an answer to this question, a follow-up question (which might be better asked as its own separate Stack Overflow question) would be:

- Can I write a formula to detect this, and fallback to some hard-coded value?

Ideally, my formula in cell `B1` would look something like this:

```
=IF(A1.Price,A1.Price,.95)
```

where `A1` is the Office 365 currency data grab, and `.95` is the fallback value. But I have no way of knowing if this would work.

Comment: The cell `A1` will show as `#UNKNOWN!` error while the formulated cell would show as `#FIELD!` since the Office 365 Currency Data Type Feature is not available for Non MS365 Users. About preserving most recent value, they might get the last updated one which you have sent. Still I have doubt about it.

Comment: That's great information, thank you. I'm not sure how to intentionally generate either the `#UNKNOWN!` or `#FIELD!` values, but do you suppose the `=IFERROR(A1.Price,.95)` function would render the expected result in such cases?

Comment: No in anyways `Non MS365` users wont get the accurate results. they will see the last updated value which you have sent them when they open it for the first time. Once they try to edit it, they will see the error in cell `A1` as  `#UNKNOWN!` while in cell `B1` as the last updated currency value which was shown in your workbook. Also using `IFERROR()` will result in only `.95` they won't get to see ever the actual price which is grabbed from Currency Data Tab in MS365 version.

Comment: May be there is a workaround using VBA, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, Your response might as well be the answer to this question. I'll rephrase the question, so that you may submit it as an answer, if you so wish.

Comment: Ah okay , you meant to say the first one (comment)?

Comment: I think the information in both the first and second comment combined was really useful.

Comment: Sounds great let me put that up, so it may help someone in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per my comments above, the cell `A1` will show as `#UNKNOWN!` error while the formulated cell would show as `#FIELD!` since the Office 365 Currency Data Type Feature is not available for Non MS365 Users. About preserving most recent value, they might get the last updated one which you have sent.

Perhaps, in anyways Non MS365 users wont get the accurate results. they will see the last updated value which you have sent them when they open it for the first time. Once they try to edit it, they will see the error in cell A1 as `#UNKNOWN!` while in cell `B1` as the last updated currency value which was shown in your workbook. Also using `IFERROR()` will result in only `.95` they won't get to see ever the actual price which is grabbed from Currency Data Tab in MS365 version.